# Python Keras define custom loss that uses pandas DataFrame as an additional argument

Tags: python, pandas, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I would like to write a custom loss function for a neural network.
The problem is:
I have such dataframe:

```
 supplier id   supplier area    revenue distance
    0           1428            27664   248.699848
    0           1428            86508   246.577731
    1           1428            39442   227.960085
    2           1428            20572   191.970242
    2           1428            92528   391.935592
```

and `X is ['supplier area', 'distance'], y is ['revenue']`

I am using `model.compile(loss=calculate_loss(data), optimizer='adam')`

to use `calculate_loss(data)` as a loss function.

I would like to define that function as something like this:

```
def calculate_loss(df):
  df1 = df.copy()   #the .copy() here is just to make sure not to mess with original df
  df1['y_pred'] = y_pred
  def lossFunction(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = K.mean(K.square(tf.cast(df1.groupby('supplier id').sum()['y_pred'], 'float32') - tf.cast(df1.groupby('supplier id').sum()['revenue'], 'float32')), axis=1)
    return loss
  return lossFunction
```

The point here is that I would like to use the existing dataframe with ID of each supplier and calculate the mean squared error on the values that are sum of grouped by the supplier ID.

Do you know any way to do it?

I can't do `df1['y_pred'] = y_pred`, because y_pred is a tf.Tensor and while grouping, the column gets lost.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You want to predict sum of revenue for a given supplier_id?

Comment: That is not actually true. I need to predict revenue for each shop (each multiple position with same supplier id represents one shop) - I will need that data. At the same time I wish to calculate loss based on the sum of revenue for a given supplier_id and then calculate MSE and optimize weights. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to calculate loss based on the sum of revenue for a given supplier id? What it your motive behind this?

Comment: I need to calculate the function for Huff gravity model and in order to do so I need to know: area of the supplier, distance between a shop and a supplier and the shops revenue.
I have now changed the code and used some basic formula to calculate 'gravity_force' (probability) and probability adjusted revenue. I want to feed the model with area, distance and that adjusted revenue.
Here comes the tricky part: for the real data I will only have the revenue of the suppliers (not shops!). So the model needs to adjust the probabilities based on the sum of revenue. Hope that calrifies a little

Comment: So the model needs to adjust the probabilities based on the sum of revenue and real data (which is a sum too) ***